# Read data from arduino on android

Tags: java, android, arduino

I have simple task to do. At start i just want to read data from arduino on my moblie device (Xperia T).

I have a problem, i always recieve 0 bytes. I wrote aplication based on:
usb serial for android

My main application is here: http://pastebin.com/JCCZN6mg
Android project is here: https://mega.co.nz/#F!X5ZxDZ5T!SvJPF8TnOijYJAtSOaO3Mw

If I connect arduino to my computer, and monitor serial port (by arduino IDE), it's working (i receive data, and TX LED blinks), but when i connect arduino to my phone, only RX LED blinks when I open the connection.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: usb serial for android: 
https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/

Comment: ok, now it's working, i just need to setDTR as true